# When Nacho has a gun to Bolsa's head, Mike says, "Do it!" -- What did he mean?

Tags: better-call-saul

Mike is watching from far away through a rifle scope. Did he mean to shoot Bolsa and if so why?

Comment: If Nacho shot Bolsa, Mike was green-lit to take out Nacho.

Comment: @JohnnyBones: But why would Mike be so hot for Bolsa to be killed? That seems like a complication.

Answer (score 2):

### Mike wanted Nacho to shoot Bolsa.

When Mike said "do it", Nacho's gun was aimed at Bolsa's head.

Screencaps immediately *before* and *after* Mike said "do it", respectively:
[image][image]

[The original plan](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/118706/1006) was for Nacho to say that he was working for a Peruvian cartel, and after that, that he run as fast as he can at Victor, who will then kill him. Mike couldn't have meant that he wanted Nacho to shoot himself, since:

1. That wasn't the original plan, and
2. Nacho hasn't aimed his gun at his own head yet at that point.

*Mike couldn't have known what Nacho will have done* (which is to shoot himself) *at that point.*

It is shown throughout the series that Mike has a certain fondness for Nacho, standing as a father figure to Nacho in the criminal world.

> **The A.V. Club:** Mike and Nacho exchanged those little nods when Mike got out of the van at the meet-up. It became a crushing moment when we saw what Nacho decided to do with Juan Bolsa’s gun.
>
> **Michael Mando:**  I think [Mike and Nacho are] both parallels of each other. In a way, Mike is a father figure for Nacho in the cartel world, and Nacho represents Mike’s son in the cartel world.

<sup>- [*Michael Mando on Nacho Varga's major moment in last night's Better Call Saul* — The A.V. Club](https://www.avclub.com/interview-michael-mando-on-playing-nacho-in-better-cal-1848838869)</sup>

Mike had been helping Nacho get out of his employment by the Salamancas since Season 2 — from Tuco, to Hector, to Lalo. Mike himself had his own reason to retaliate against the Salamancas since Hector threatened to kill Kaylee, his granddaughter. (Mike's attempt to kill Hector is how he came to be employed by Gus in the first place.) Mike and Gus also don't see eye to eye on how Gus is treating Nacho. The fact that Gus is threatening Nacho's father's life doesn't sit well with Mike, and he let this be known to Gus. In many ways, Mike is more loyal to Nacho than to Gus. Mike even tried to convince Gus to let go of Nacho:

> **Mike:** There's one other thing we should discuss.
> Nacho Varga. He wants out. He's done everything we asked. He held up his end. I think it's time we cut him loose.
> **Gus:** I see no reason to give up an asset.
> **Mike:** Once Salamanca's dealt with, we have no use for Varga. He's the only guy they have running things up here. He disappears, Salamanca operation falls apart.
> **Gus:** Varga stays. Better to control the opposition without their knowledge.
> **Mike:** [*Sighs*] You have a gun to his father's head. That doesn't sit with me. You want to keep Varga for the long run, I don't think fear is a great motivator.
> **Gus:** A dog who bites every owner he's had... can only be disciplined with a firm hand. Or... put down.

<sup>- *Better Call Saul* S05E09 "Bad Choice Road"</sup>

Mike cared so much for Nacho that Gus had Tyreese point his gun at Mike (S06E02 "Carrot and Stick"). Gus noticed Mike's conflict of interest regarding what to do with Nacho and was willing to kill Mike at that point. Gus didn't even order Mike to come with them to the desert, and Mike has to convince Gus to allow him to come.

#### Mike would want Nacho to have a  final act of defiance or a final revenge against those in the criminal world that have ruined Nacho's life.

He'd probably have the same reaction had Nacho pointed his gun at Hector, or *even Gus*.

---

On the other hand, Michael Mando (Nacho) says that "Mike is conflicted" and that he's "not really sure what Mike is really thinking anymore":

> **Entertainment Weekly:** When Mike is watching Nacho hold the gun to Bolsa's head, he mutters, "Do it." Is he hoping that Nacho would kill Bolsa, or is he saying, "Do your job," which is, "Die and ensure your father's safety." And with the gun, Nacho can now end things on his terms.
>
> **Michael Mando:** I think Mike is a conflicted character morally at this point. For most of the show, Nacho's been looking at Mike for guidance. In this point, Nacho transcends that relationship. I'm not really sure what Mike is really thinking anymore; you have to ask Jonathan Banks that, because the characters — even though there's still a deep love and respect for each other — have sworn allegiances to different sides. Nacho is breaking good and Mike is breaking bad, and they kind of leave each other at that point.

<sup>- [*Better Call Saul star Michael Mando breaks down Nacho's fate* — Entertainment Weekly](https://ew.com/tv/better-call-saul-michael-mando-on-nacho-fate-rock-hard-place/)</sup>

Comment: The fundamental idea is, Nacho wants his father to be protected. He is willingly giving up his life to try to ensure this, incidentally enduring a beating (I guess no big deal at that point), and reading from a script provided by Fring. Any deviation from what Fring wants risks everything which is why I am puzzled -- maybe Nacho at the last minute imagined he could escape? But that does not make much sense, since even if he could pull off that longshot, his father would then almost certainly be murdered.

Answer (score 1):

### Mike wanted Nacho to shoot himself.

His words meant he wanted Nacho to shoot himself. That was the plan and the deal with Fring. The longer Nacho delayed, the more likely he gets shot in the shoulder and lose the use of the arm holding the gun, which would lead to him being taken alive and dying horribly after giving up Fring under torture.

### Shooting Bolsa would have harmed Fring's position and by extension put Mike in jeopardy.

Mike wouldn't want him to kill Bolsa because Bolsa is Fring's biggest supporter in the Cartel heirarchy. Repeatedly throughout the series, we see Bolsa taking Fring's side against the Salamancas and advocating on Fring's behalf. Killing Bolsa would have been a disaster for Fring and Mike.