# Why did Nacho deviate from the plan by grabbing Bolsa?

Tags: better-call-saul

In *Better Call Saul* S06E03 "Rock and Hard Place", the fundamental idea was, to do what was agreed upon with Fring and his father will be protected -- anything would seem to jeopardize that protection.

He knew no matter what he did, he was going to die. Probably within moments, almost zero chance of escaping just because he held Bolsa -- the Twins would not care. Not sure if Nacho knew Mike was there with a rifle but Mike also might have shot him.

But even if somehow he got away, he would be found eventually, soon, and then both he certainly and his father (probably) would die.

And this was not a spur-of-the-moment thing -- he planned it when he saw the broken glass. The only idea I have is he was worried about someone else shooting him, he wanted to shoot himself although I am not convinced that was his plan from the outset.

One further idea: This could have been Fring's idea to add authenticity -- Fring may have felt that one of his own men shooting him would not seem real enough but Nacho's move could easily have failed, Bolsa could have gotten away, perhaps.

Comment: This seems to contain an answer already—you do know that it's fine to answer your question yourself, right?

Comment: @Joachim: If I were sure, I would not post the question -- I want arguments against my ideas, not just to proudly post questions with my own answers. I take this forum fairly seriously and try to show that I have thought already about the issue.

Comment: I was just making sure you knew that. And if you take this *non-forum* fairly seriously, you might also know that your setup is not the right away to use it: this is not the right place to have your (subjective) interpretations—something that the best movies and series work with—refuted (hence my vote to close it as opinion-based).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The original plan was for Nacho to say that he was working for a Peruvian cartel, and after that, that he run as fast as he can at Victor, who will then kill him:

> **Gus:** What will you say?
> **Nacho:** I'll say it was Alvarez. Working for Los Odios out of Peru. That, um... I've been on the payroll for almost a year.
> **Mike:** Alright. Once you say it, you get to your feet. You start running
> as fast as you can at Victor. You'll be zip-tied, he'll be ready. Get past him
> and keep running. He'll handle it.
> **Nacho:** He puts me down, you mean.
> **Mike:** It'll be over quick.

His speech towards the Salamancas ("*I would've done it for free, because I hate every last one of you psycho sacks of shit*"), him admitting what he did to Hector ("*I put you in that chair*"), and grabbing Bolsa, are deviations from the original plan. Michael Mando (actor who played Nacho) explained why Nacho deviated from the plan in interviews:

> **TVLine:** Nacho has that great final speech and gets a chance to tell off Hector Salamanca in his final moments. It looked very satisfying for him. Was it satisfying for you to deliver?
>
> **Michael Mando:** That moment, to me, had a lot of subtext to it. I think Nacho was really, in a way, standing up for his community, and he felt that his community was more the integrity and virtue of his father. He was swearing allegiance to that and standing up to the cartel. That, to me, was such a noble moment full of integrity, where so much was being said in the subtext of it, and I thought it was just beautifully written by [executive producer] Gordon Smith.

> **TVLine:** Nacho does manage to break free, and he grabs a gun and holds Juan Bolsa hostage. But then he turns the gun on himself. Was that just his way of controlling his own destiny, and kind of going out on his own terms?
>
> **Michael Mando:** Well, he has made the decision, firm and sound, that he was going to exchange his life for his father. And if you go back to the beginning of Season 1, Nacho has always kept his word with Mike. He’s been utterly loyal to Mike. At the end of Season 5, his gesture is a brave heroic gesture of loyalty, where he [goes] against the cartel to swear allegiance to Mike. He’s always been loyal. In that moment, he’s just true to his word.

> **TVLine:** Well, it’s a great showcase episode for you and for Nacho. Do you feel like you got a fitting send-off at least, even if he had to leave early?
>
> **Michael Mando:** I think you couldn’t ask for a better ending. You know, this character ended up being a dream role for me. Such a heroic and symbolic figure of sacrifice and courage. I wouldn’t change an iota. I’m just so eternally grateful for it.
>
> It’s more important why you go. We all go. We all transcend. I think it’s important why we transcend and how we transcend, and how we feel about our lives. And Nacho, in that moment, has zero regrets. It’s actually the most Zen we’ve probably ever seen him, because he knows who he is. For the first time in his life, he has a clear image of himself.

<sup>- [*Better Call Saul's Michael Mando Breaks Down Nacho's 'Heroic' Episode* — TVLine](https://tvline.com/2022/04/25/better-call-saul-recap-season-6-episode-3-nacho-dies/)</sup>

> **The A.V. Club:** Nacho’s whole final speech at the desert meet-up is brilliant. What was his main motivation in telling Hector he was the one who caused his stroke?
>
> **Michael Mando:** There’s a lot going on sub textually in that scene. For one, Nacho swears allegiance to the side of good and sort of revokes the privileges of the cartel. He turns down the highest position from Don Eladio, turns down the money and the power in order to protect the integrity and the virtue of his father. And there’s a community element to that, too, where Nacho kind of stands up for what he aspires for, for his father and his community. So he’s taking a stance, in that situation.

<sup>- [*Michael Mando on Nacho Varga's major moment in last night's Better Call Saul* — The A.V. Club](https://www.avclub.com/interview-michael-mando-on-playing-nacho-in-better-cal-1848838869)</sup>

> **Vanity Fair:** It seems like Nacho went out on his own terms. Was that important to you?
>
> **Michael Mando:** You know, these characters are not real. They’re icons and they represent symbols. And though it’s very tragic, Nacho is a character who transcends himself and transcends his physical environment. His iconography becomes larger than life, and beyond the constraints of greed and power. He stands up for something, for an ideology, which essentially is embodied in his father.

<sup>- [*Nacho Actor Michael Mando on Better Call Saul Season 6 Shocker: “Brace Yourself”* — Vanity Fair](https://www.vanityfair.com/hollywood/2022/04/better-call-saul-nacho-michael-mando-603)</sup>